# Are FOR loops with char iterators in C possible?

Tags: c, for-loop, iterator, char, unsigned

I'm having a problem using an unsigned char as an iterator. Using the following code results in being stuck inside a FOR loop. [The output looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIAJI.png)

```
unsigned char i;
char * arr;
int * freq;
arr = (char *)(malloc(256*sizeof(char)));
freq = (int *)(malloc(256*sizeof(int)));
for (i=0; i<=255;i++){
    arr[i]=i;
    freq[i]=0;
    printf("%c",i);
}
```

My question is why this happens? Is it due to using an unsigned char as an iterator?

Comment: Since `unsigned char i` cannot hold a value greater than 255. `i<=255` is always true.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And `sizefo(char)` is _defined_ to yield `1`. There is no use in explicitly writing it.

Comment: Also, using a char as an iterator is not likely to be more "efficient" you may as well use an integer. I could be wrong though

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald: The correct type for an interator on an array would be `size_t` (which is unsigned). Alternatively `unsigned int` can be used, if the values are guaranteed to be `<= SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @chux: `255` is the minum maximum(!) value required by the standard. There is no statment an `unsigned char` can not hold larger values.

Comment: @Olaf Its hard to say what is "correct". It depends on the purpose. In terms of efficiency, there is debate in the comments of the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860918/gcc-hinting-at-vectorization/34920949#34920949

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`. That is in units of `char`s, which is guaranteed to be the smalles possible array-element, Thus `size_t` guarantees correct indxing of an array **under all circumstances** and for all types. An `int` may not provide that, e.g. for typical 32 bit systems with both types having 32 bits, if >2GiB address space is available.

Answer (score 9):

```
i <= 255
```

If `i` is of type `unsigned char` and that type is 8 bit on your platform (which it likely is), then the expression will always be `true` and you have an infinite loop. It is well-defined behavior, though. The `unsigned char` will simply wrap around and its value will start at 0 again once it has reached 255.

The solution is simple of course: change the type of `i` to `int`.

To avoid such surprises in the future, make sure to turn on your compiler's warnings. If I compile the bogus loop with GCC and pass it the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags, it will tell me this.

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:17: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
   for (i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
                 ^
```

Comment: Correct type is `size_t`.

Comment: For general array sizes, yes. But the standard guarantees that an `int` will be able to hold values up to 2^15 – 1 so it would be fine in this case.

Comment: How to turn on compiler's warning?

Comment: @MASh If you're using GCC or Clang, with the flags mentioned in the answer. For other compilers, consult their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Primary issue: Since `unsigned char i` cannot hold a value greater than `UCHAR_MAX`. `i<=255` is always true. `UCHAR_MAX` is commonly 255, as it certainly is on OP's platform, but may be more.

Other notes:

When using an array index, best to use `size_t`.

Casting `malloc()` results is not needed.  Also consider multiple by the size of the variable and not the size of the type. - IMO: easier to maintain and code correctly.

Avoid magic numbers 256, 255 floating about.

```
#define N 256
size_t i;
char * arr;
int * freq;
arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * N);
freq = malloc(sizeof *freq * N);
for (i=0; i<N;i++){
    arr[i]=i;
    freq[i]=0;
    printf("%c",i);
}
```

Comment: @Olaf Not-so-quirky notation? ^^ I just remembered how it's expressed in the standard, so I used that.

Answer (score 0):

Because your condition is `i <= 255`, when `i` becomes `255`, it will be incremented by one. The maximum range of an `unsigned char` at **your** machine is [0,255], so it just wrap around to zero again. So the loop, continues for ever.

This issue is known as arithmetic or [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: I would write "The maximum range of an unsigned char is [0,255] **[on your machine]**" instead. Emphasis added. `unsigned char` is **at least** 8 bits, not at most.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop does the following: It performs the initialisation. Then it checks the loop condition. If the loop condition is true, it performs the loop, then the increment expression. And then it checks the loop condition again. This is *literally* what it does.

When i = 255, and i++ is executed, the compiler tries to set i to 256, but because it is an unsigned char and likely 8 bit, that 256 is truncated to zero. And then the loop condition i <= 255 is again true. The compiler follows *exactly* what you told it to do, not what you wanted it to do.

Comment: Small correction: The compiler will not do anything to the contents of the variables. It just generates the code.